# Width of gradient increases on zoom out?

Tags: html, css

I have created a div that uses a linear gradient. When I zoom out (and or zoom in) my gradient shrinks and grows depending on how much I zoom out or in, I set a specific width to try to stop this. It didn't work.

```css
body{
  background: linear-gradient(200deg,#aebcbf -10%,#6e7774 110%,#0a0809 1000%);
  background-repeat:no-repeat
}

img {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-play-state: playing;
  float: left;
  opacity:0.5;
  border-radius:90%;
}

h1{
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-variant-caps:titling-caps;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #FFFFFF;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#css-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, white);
  width:47%;
  border-style:outset;
  background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div id="css-gradient">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png" draggable="false">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png" draggable="false">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png" draggable="false">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png" draggable="false">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png" draggable="false">
  <div style="clear: left;"></div>
  <input type=color style="width:15px;height:100px;position:absolute;left:635px;top:8px;height:125px">
  <h1 title="If successful this will be in a white box">Hover over me!</h1>
  <hr style="width:300px;position:relative;top:-5px;border-style:double">
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ffksjqp2/1/)

Comment: For anyone else having this problem (zoom out and zoom in object changes width) then you need to set the width in px, since when it is set in % it takes "XX%" of the page, even after zoom out. Thanks for helping though :>

Answer (score 1):

Im not sur I understood your problem. Do you mean a zoom in / zoom out with your browser ?
Anyway you can try this with your css-gradient class :

```
#css-gradient {
      background: linear-gradient(blue, white);
      background-attachment: fixed;
      width:47%;
      border-style:outset;
      background-repeat:no-repeat
    }
```